# Why is my regex not working in C# but working in other text editors?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a Regex as follows:

Pattern: `<navPoint id="navPoi[^"]+" playOrder="[^"]+"><navLabel><text>([^<>\r\n]+)</text></navLabel><content src="([^<>\r\n]+)"/>$`

Substitution: `<li id="NavPoint-#"><a href="$2">$1</a>\r\n<ol>`

It works in normal editors and even in regex101: [Demo with Input](https://regex101.com/r/a8crnt/1)

I want to write the same in C#, but when I do, it does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
string secondPattern = @"<navPoint id=""navPoi[^""]+"" playOrder=""[^""]+""><navLabel><text>([^<>\n]+)<\/text><\/navLabel><content src=""([^<>\n]+)""\/>$";
string secondSubstitution = @"<li id=""NavPoint-#""><a href=""$2"">$1</a>\r\n<ol>";
Regex secondRegex = new Regex(secondPattern, options);
string anotherNavMap = secondRegex.Replace(newNavMap, secondSubstitution);
```

Comment: So, shall I replace `\r\n` with `\R\n` or just `\R`?

Comment: I am working on Windows 10 Pro using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: `\R` is equivalent to `(\n|\r|\r\n)`.

Comment: `\R` gave me an `Escape Sequence` error and `\r?\n` also did not work.

Comment: Ok, just noticed something in your regex which could be the issue. You have `[^<>\n]` which could be missing `\r` inside it. Try putting `\r` inside it.

Comment: Same result, no replacements. The thing is that I tried multiple times. Copying the data in the variable and pasting it in `regex101` or `Notepad++` or `UltraEdit`, everywhere the pattern does the find and replace perfectly. I don't know what happened in `C#`.

Comment: `new Regex(secondPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);` and change `$` with `\r?$` (at the end of the pattern). Do not try `\R`, it is not supported in .NET regex. `\R` is an equivalent of `(?>\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])`, not of `(\n|\r|\r\n)`, but it won't help here. Why do you parse HTML with regex when you have HtmlAgilityPack in C#?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Works. Really appreciate it. But now during replacement, the `\r\n` is coming as text instead of a new line, how do I do that?

Comment: Oh, you should not use a verbatim string literal.

Comment: I used `@"<li id=""NavPoint-#""><a href=""$2"">$1</a>" + Environment.NewLine + "<ol>";` and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure you pass `RegexOptions.Multiline` option to the regex compile, and allow the CR before the `$` end of line anchor as `$` in multiline mode only matches before an LF symbol.

Also, `@"\r\n"` is a string of 4 characters, if you need a CRLF linebreak, use `"\r\n"`, as verbatim string literals do not support string escape sequences.

Here is a code fix:

```
string secondPattern = @"<navPoint id=""navPoi[^""]+"" playOrder=""[^""]+""><navLabel><text>([^<>\n]+)</text></navLabel><content src=""([^<>\n]+)""/>\r?$";
string secondSubstitution = "<li id=\"NavPoint-#\"><a href=\"$2\">$1</a>\r\n<ol>";
Regex secondRegex = new Regex(secondPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string anotherNavMap = secondRegex.Replace(newNavMap, secondSubstitution);
```

Comment: Don't you still have a `\r` in that first verbatim string, though?

Comment: @Nyerguds In a regex, `\r` matches  a CR symbol. Same is with `\n`. So, a regex defined with `@"\r"` is equal to `"\\r"` and it matches CR symbol. `@"\r"` regex (``\`` and `r` combination) = `"\r"` (CR symbol) regex.

Comment: i just found out that if the data between the `<text>Is this a valid input?</text>`, ends with a special character like `?`, `!`, `%` or anything, the pattern does not work, is there any update that can be done?

Comment: @Omanshu Please share the exact code reproducing the behavior. Use ideone.com or dotnetfiddle.com